# Update part of View Model based on dropdown selected item change in MVC Web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Having trouble finding a solution to this problem.

Part of the form contains a multiple row table that displays users that have an assigned role in the activity. It is part of complex form with many other sections.

I'd like to change the user based on a dropdownlist of available users and have that reflected in the ViewModel such that when a subsequent "Save" button is clicked on the form, the changed user will be saved back to the database.  I'm stuck trying to figure out how to make this happen.

I have the following javascript in place that responds to a dropdwonlist change event and it works as expected on the change event, but don't know how to update the ViewModel.

```
    $("#RecipientsName").change(function () {
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetUser","Controller")';
        var data = { id: $(this).val() };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Get',
            url: url,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (userInfo) {
                $('#UpdatedRecipientName').text('Hey');  // This does update the view
                alert(userInfo.Result);
            },
            error: function (userInfo) {
                alert('Failed');
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is the Method in the controller, it simply returns the passed in string at the moment.

```
    public ActionResult GetUser(string id)
    {

        return Json(new {Result = id},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

It seems like this should be a fairly thing to accomplish, but have not found a solution as of yet.  Maybe I'm approaching this all wrong, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC interprets view models based on the name of the control.

So if say your view model looks something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SomeProperty1 {get;set;}
    public string SomeProperty2 {get;set;}
}
```

On your form, you should have something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="SomeProperty1"/>
<input type="text" name="SomeProperty1"/>
```

Example of full view:

```
@model TestMVC.Models.MyViewModel


<h2>TestAction</h2>

<script>
    function ChangeValue() {
        var textbox = document.getElementById('MyElementToChange1');
        textbox.value = 'Property 5';
    }
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>MyViewModel</legend>

    Some Property 1
            <input name="SomeProperty1" type="text" value="@Model.SomeProperty1" id="MyElementToChange1"/>

            Some Property 2
            <input name="SomeProperty2" type="text" value="@Model.SomeProperty2" id="MyElementToChange2"/>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<input type="button" value="Change Value" onclick="ChangeValue()"/>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

The controller you're submitting to can just have something like:

```
    public ActionResult TestAction()
    {
        MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();
        viewModel.SomeProperty1 = "Property 1";
        viewModel.SomeProperty2 = "Property 2";
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestAction(MyViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

With this example, if you click on the button in the view, it changes the value of the SomeProperty1 to 5, and if you check the ActionResult TestAction(MyViewModel viewModel) method, you'll see that you have 5 as the value for SomeProperty1.

All you have to do with the javascript is update the input control that has the same name as the property you want to update and it will be used as part of the view model submitted to the Action. Note that you can't use labels for this - if you have a property that you want the user not to be able to modify, you should use a hidden input to store the value.

**Edit: Added more to the view to show the javascript**

Comment: I'm not quite sure if it does.  Could you add a little more clarity around the change function in terms of how to pass the ViewModel to the controller method and within the controller method would you return View(viewModel)? and in the javascript do this? $('#SomeProperty1').text('some value');

Comment: Also as an FYI this process of grabbing the values from the form and creating them into an object in the action method parameter is referred to a 'model binding' - might help for future googling.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i was able to resolve my issue based on your reply.

Comment: Ohh man great. I knew about this just not used in a context like THIS :) Really simplifies everything. +1